# Pressing back button

Tags: android, gridview

I on an android work stuff. I have a gridView displaying images. When I click on one image, a imageView with text of each own and a back button appear. There is an particular xml layout for them. When I click the back button I want the gridview goes back but not close the main activity. Note only mainactivity!
So you guys, is there any suggestion to help me.
Here is my mainactivity's code:

```
Bundle myBackupBundle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myBackupBundle = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    tvMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMsg);
```

Here:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    showdetails(position);
}
private void showdetails(int position){
    setContentView(R.layout.solo_picture);
    tvSoloMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSoloMsg);
    tvSoloMsg.setText("Image at" + position);
    ivSoloPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSolo);
    ivSoloPicture.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnback);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onCreate(myBackupBundle);//When I press back button, I got trouble here

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post what you have done already

Comment: Try to use fragment instead of activity to showing image with text..

Comment: Yes, post some some code or your xml. Only then we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag.

```
int imageOpenFlag = 0;
```

//Make this playing flag 1 when one image is clicked,by making its value 1

```
imageOpenFlag = 1;
```

//In your onBackPressed method,check this flag.If it is 1,close image,if its 0,close main activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    if( imageOpenFlag == 1 ) {
       //Do something you want
       //go back in gridview
    } else {
        //close activity
    }
}
```